# React Native Webview is not download automatically. Both ios and android

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

The webview not download file automatically to device.  In html, I use a link tag and set attribute as download. In webview ios, just open and preview that file but not download automatically. At the same time, android nothing happened and reload page. I should fix in web script for download or it possible to setting or something in native app via webview ?

"react-native": "0.70.6",
"react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",

```
<Webview
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
    allowFileAccess={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    mixedContentMode={'always'} 
/>
```

In my web script

```
const downloadFileFromObjectUrl = (source, filename) => {
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(source)
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = downloadUrl
    link.setAttribute('download', filename)
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
    link.remove()
}
```

Thank everyone for suggestion.